# webrtc used as a simile message app

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to write a small application usingwebrtc that can be used as a messaging/Chat application between 2 computers.

I see this:
http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/

and it is not working. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the [simpl.info/rtcdatachannel](http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel) example. It's only designed to show off data channels working within one page.

For a complete peer-to-peer messaging application, I suggest adding RTCDataChannel functionality to something like [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com). You could also consider a readymade abstraction library like [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) or [EasyRTC](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc).

You might also want to take a look at the RTCPeerConnection/RTCDataChannel/signaling [codelab](http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) I built.

Answer (score 0):

In above example, from the trace log, the **ice-candidates** are generated, but they are either not **exchanged** between each other because of there may be problem in sending `'offer'` or responding the `'answer'`.  Also above example works only in chrome( because of only  *`webkitRTCPeerConnection`* is used, with *`mozRTCPeerConnection`* this can work on firefox also.

If you want to develope chat application for only text and not for the video chat, then you can use **node-js** & **socket.io** or **websockets** for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may like :) following two libraries:

1. [DataChannel.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/DataChannel) / for webrtc data/text/file sharing (among multi-users)
2. [RTCMultiConnection.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection) / for data as well as media (screen/audio/video/etc) sharing

Firebase.com is a "suggested" starting point for newcomers; that can be used for signaling. You just need to override "[openSignalingChannel](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection#custom-signaling-v14-and-earlier)" and done!

Answer (score 0):

You should use peer.js (https://github.com/peers/peerjs) or use peer chat (https://github.com/Hironate/PeerChat) if you want to do with node js.